# How to prevent two Top Most windows from competing for visibility when moving?

Tags: c, winapi

My executable creates a window that constantly moves left and right using `SetWindowPos` on a 1millisecond timer.

When NOT given the WS_EX_TOPMOST style, opening two of the executables would have the second window being consistantly covered by the first window while both windows are moving.

However, once I gave the executable the WS_EX_TOPMOST style, running the executable twice would have both windows consistantly competing to be shown above one another.

I'm trying to make the windows topmost so they would always be shown, but not compete for visibility.

I suspected this issue to occur because of something to do with the Z order of topmost Windows, so I tried to arrange the Z order as such:

```
//prior to this, the window is NOT given the WS_EX_TOPMOST style

case WM_CREATE:
{
HWND testhWnd=FindWindow("name","name");
int exStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);

//Check if previous instance of window that was promoted to TOPMOST exists

if((exStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) ==WS_EX_TOPMOST)
//Precede current window over previous window in Z order
{
SetWindowPos(hwnd,testhWnd,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
}
else
{
SetWindowPos(hwnd,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
}

break;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Is there even Z indexing in Topmost windows? How can I fix this issue? Thank you for reading!

Comment: *"How can I fix this issue?"* - You can't. You just need to run the [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) thought experiment to arrive at that conclusion.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah I see, I was assuming top windows to simply be a class of windows, with their own Z-order independent of non-topmost windows, meaning that if a non-topmost window was brought forward, it would only go as far as the lowest z-order topmost window. Guess that idea is quite off from reality